# Что выполняет |

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте в чужом коде встретил строку на подобии `number = number << 8 | mass[6];`
и мне крайне любопытно что означает | это что то вроде сокращенного или?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть документацию https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Мы не видим типов в примере. Если предположить `unsigned char mass[]`, то в данном случае это эквивалентно `number * 256 + mass[6]`. Иногда таким образом в одном числе (скажем, типа `unsigned int`) упаковывают несколько чисел (каждое небольшой разрядности). Это применимо в некоторых протоколах передачи данных (или при работе непосредственно  с  регистрами аппаратуры)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` - это оператор побитового ИЛИ

например :

```
auto x = 5;
auto y = 9;
std::cout << (x | y) << std::endl;
```

Программа выведет в консоль 13. так как :

- 5 в двоичной форме 00000101
- 9 в двоичной форме 00001001
- в свою очередь 13 в двоичной форме - 00001101

Полезные ссылки :

[wikipedia. Битовая операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#:%7E:text=0001-,%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98,%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2.)

[MSDN. Bitwise inclusive OR operator: |](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/bitwise-inclusive-or-operator-pipe?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Приоритет `<<` выше чем у `|`. Программа ничего не выведет в консоль, т.к. [не валидная](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/761e61ff2cef4c84).

Comment: @wololo,  для вывода в cout x | y надо взять в скобки -- `cout << (x | y) << '\n';`

Comment: @wololo спасибо что заметили!